# Firebase Streambuilder is not changing login state after navigating

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Here, i am trying to implement Firebase login and signup system. i am trying to change screen base on user login or not.

Basically, i want to show feed screen when user is login and when user is not login i want to show login scree. if i do login in login screen it is working fine, so i did not added that code here. but issue come when i navigate from login screen to sign up scree and even if i successfully sign up it is not showing me feed screen. When i hot reload it show me feed screen.

Moreover, i also make sure that it is reaching where i am changing screen by print in console.

Note: i know i can using function to change between login screen and signup screen, so i don't need Navigator, which will again work for me. but i want to know why after navigating using navigator it is not working.

```
class DeleteWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _DeleteWidgetState createState() => _DeleteWidgetState();
}

class _DeleteWidgetState extends State<DeleteWidget> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: StreamBuilder<FirebaseUser>(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged,
          builder: (BuildContext context, snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.hasData);
            print(snapshot.connectionState);
            if (ConnectionState.active == snapshot.connectionState) {
              print("object 1");
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
                print("object 2");
                return Feed();
              } else {
                print("object 3");
                return LoginScreen();
              }
            } else {
              return LoginScreen();
            }
          }),
    );
  }
}

class LoginScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("login"),
            onPressed: () async {
              Navigator.push(
                  context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => SignUp()));
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class SignUp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("Sign up"),
            onPressed: () async {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInAnonymously();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Feed extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Container(
          child: RaisedButton(
            child: Text("feed"),
            onPressed: () async {
              await FirebaseAuth.instance.signOut();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Please review your code. Your signup widget is signing in and your login widget is pushing to the signup screen. Review your code and update it. @Viren V Varasadiya

Comment: i am just using this code to replicate my issue. i am sign in anonymously to show that i am login over there. i just want to know when i am navigating from login screen to signup screen and sign up over there it is not changing to feed screen. @T.TSage

Comment: Hi @Viren, did you manage to solve the problem? I am having the same issues when combining StreamProvider and navigation. After registering, although the stream gets called the page does not refresh

Comment: Hi @VirenVVarasadiya Did you solved this issue? I have the same issue.

Comment: I have same Issue

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Provider Package](https://pub.dev/packages/provider) to Listen if user is logged in and use a Wrapper to direct the user to the correct screen. If the user logs out at any stage, they will be automatically redirected to the Login Screen.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.

User _userFromFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<User>.value(
      value: FirebaseAuth.instance.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFromFirebaseUser),
      child: MaterialApp(
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Wrapper

```
class Wrapper extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    if(user == null) {
      return LoginScreen();
    } else {
      return Feed();
    }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. But my question is why after using navigator it is not working. I know many other option is available as you suggested.

Comment: I believe its because you need to `setState` - The page doesn't know it needs to re-draw

Comment: it is changing screen if i login in login screen, but it is not changing screen when navigating to signup screen and then login. OR where i have to call setState, because if i setState in StreamBuilder then it throws error. setState is called while building.